# How a process is created in a processor?

Tags: linux, unix, process, linux-kernel, kernel

When I execute a program in unix/Linux, what really happens under the hood?

Who is responsible for creating a process?

Do I need to make a call to kernel to start a process (instance of my program) ? In that sense, my program should be running on a processor to make kernel calls right? Then how does the first kernel call happened to start of a process? . Is it like a deadlock? Where exactly kernel first show-in then?

Sorry, I just read many documents about all these, but still couldn't connect the dots or get a full picture. Can someone elaborate on simple terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Unix systems (as well as most modern non-Unix systems), processes are a tree - every process has a parent process (except for the process with Process ID 1, the init process, which is created by the kernel at startup).

When you log in to a system, you are usually logged into an instance of "shell" program (program = executable file, shell = user interaction). On Windows, `Explorer.exe` is the shell. On Unix systems, traditionally your shell is something like `bash`. On Linux desktops, you have a graphical environment like Gnome which is your shell, and you can use it to run programs like `gnome-terminal` which happens to run another program which then happens to be a text-based shell like `bash` rather than graphical shell.

Whether your run your program from Gnome, from `bash`, or from any other program `P`, whether interactive or not, `P` is the parent process of your process, which we will call `C`, and so `P` is the process that jump-starts the creation of `C`.

The way it works in Unix, usually, is as follows:

1. `P` is actually running on some CPU.
2. `P` calls the `fork()` system call, which is a kernel API.
3. In response, the kernel creates a copy of process `P` as a new process, `C`.

- At that point, `C` is not running on any CPU.
- Now you have 2 processes, `P` and `C` are 2 separate instances of the same program.

4. When the kernel's scheduler decides that it's time to run `C`, it selects a CPU, and sets that CPU's stack pointers, data pointers, code pointers, and page tables to point to the appropriate addresses in `C`'s memory.
5. The CPU is basically hardware that runs a loop that always executes the next code pointer ("instruction pointer"), so once you set the code pointer to new code, it will run the new code.

- Note that the new code - in `C` - is still a copy of the old code - in `P`.

6. Now that `C` is running, it calls the `execve()` system call, which is another kernel API.

- This is part of the parent process' logic to launch a program - you call `fork()`, then you check whether you're the original `P` or the clone `C`, and if you're `C`, you call `execve()`.

7. In response, the kernel creates a new memory space ("address space") which will contain the new program's heap, stacks, code etc., loads the executable into this memory, and then declares this new memory to be "process `C`".

- Part of loading an executable into memory is creating new appropriate addresses of stack pointers, data pointers, code pointers, and page tables that the CPU can eventually point to.
- In particular, the address for the code pointer is the address of the new program's entry point.

8. (I'm simplifying here) the kernel's scheduler then again sets the CPU's pointers to those `C` - essentially "rescheduling" it. Only now those point to the new memory space.
9. When control goes back from the kernel to `C`, it is now pointing to the new program's entrypoint, which will eventually call `main()`.

Comment: hi can you point me to some documentation for the process that you just described.

Answer (score 1):

Your program start by someone else not by your program (otherwise it will be the egg and the chicken paradox). Let's say that you run the program from some shell, the shell does the kernel call to the Linux kernel function which responsible for initiating a new process. It initiate the memory space required by your program and call its main. Now every time your program needs something which requires cpl3 it call a kernel function.